# Scala - Return value from an anonymous function

Tags: scala

I've a named function that as an Either[A, List[B]] as return type. Inside that named function, I have a anonymous function that I'd like to make it return a value to the named function. Instead I keep getting the error "Non local returns are no longer supported; use scala.util.control.NonLocalReturns instead".

I did some research but wasn't able to find a solution.

Am I missing something? Is there any to workaround this problem?

Here's my code

```
def readEvents(SchedulingNode: Node): Either[Error, List[Event]] =
    val events: List[Either[Error, Event]] = SchedulingNode.child
      .filter(n => n.label == EVENT_NODE_NAME)
      .map(n => {
        val head: Head = n.attribute(HEAD_ATTRIBUTE) match {
          case None => return Left(EmptyProperty("head")) //Error occurs here
          case Some(s) => Head.from(s.toString()) match
            case Left(e: Error) => return Left(e); //Here also
            case Right(h: Head) => h
        }

        Event.from(head, 1) match {
          case Left(e: Error) => Left(e);
          case Right(ev: Event) => Right(ev)
        }

      }).toList
    //Rest of the code...
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `NonLocalReturns` as the error suggests? - The other option would be to use something like `traverse` from **cats** or just rollout your own `foldLeft` or recursive function.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being really dumb, but how am I supposed to use it? I tried but it returned the value to events val instead.

Comment: `def readEvents(SchedulingNode: Node): Either[Error, List[Event]] = NonLocalReturns.returning { // your current code }` and instead of `return Left(...)` you would `NonLocalReturns.throwReturn(Left(...))`

Comment: I also have to point out `map` is really not supposed to be short circuited. You are essentially **mapping** the entire domain of `f` to some image. It kinda undermines the whole purpose if it's not continuous in the domain.  I am going to advocate that a proper recursive function is what is needed here and will be much easier to reason about